# SDL found with PkgConfig and MSVC (does not compile)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, cross-platform, pkg-config

I am trying to set up a cross platform project.
In Windows I have installed package *SDL2* with *MSYS2* for *x86* and *x64*.

In my *CMakeLists.txt* I have:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_search_module(SDL2
        REQUIRED sdl2 sdl
        IMPORTED_TARGET)
if(TARGET PkgConfig::SDL2)
    message(STATUS "Found SDL2")
endif()
```

Package seems to be found both for *MinGW* and *MSVC*.

Simple program compiles with *MinGW*

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

#undef main

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

However with *MSVC* *SDL* header can't be found and the program does not compile.

```
C:\dev\repos\UWCASdk\Sandbox\JoySDL\joyTest.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SDL/SDL.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx86\x64\cl.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Is it not possible to use *PkgConfig* with *MSVC*? Or should I use another package manager?

Comment: Even if pkg config worked with msvc mingw package would be still useless. It would be a better idea to download and build sdl from source.

Comment: I would want to keep my Cmake script rather simple and compatible both with Linux and Windows. With MinGW it is not a problem at all. But in case I will download and build from source I will have to add custom *FindSDL2.cmake* script. And there will be different usages hence different target names. I'd like to avoid that...